# MariaDB SQL insert with select

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert

i would get any id from table_b and add this result into INSERT in table_a

if i try this, work fine

```
INSERT INTO table_a(id)
SELECT table_b.id
FROM table_b
```

but i must insert also some other data but i can do it. These are some tests failed!

**test 1**

```
INSERT INTO table_a(a,id)
SELECT 2000 as a,table_b.id
FROM table_b
```

1054 - Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

**test 2**

```
INSERT INTO table_a(a,id)
SELECT 2000,table_b.id
FROM table_b
```

1054 - Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

**test 3**

```
INSERT INTO table_a (table_a.col1,table_a.id) VALUES (a,id)
SELECT 2000,table_b.id
FROM table_b
```

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a,id)

Comment: Does table_a actually contain the column `a`?

Comment: table a have 4 columns a,b,c,d where d=id in table_b.id

Comment: Lose the alias.

Comment: `1054 - Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'` seems to suggest that table_a does not have a column called `a`.

Comment: ok undestand with your suggest!for each column taken in "SELECT" it corresponds in the "index" of the "INSERT" in which I must indicate the "correct" columns of table A

columns A in table_a have the real name col_A INSERT INTO table_a(col_a,tb_b_id)
SELECT 2000,table_b.id
FROM table_b

Answer (score 1):

You need the same number   of column  (and corresponding data type)

```
INSERT INTO table_a(a,id)
SELECT 2000 , id 
FROM table_b
```

Answer (score -1):

TABLE A have col_a, tb_b_id

correct SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO table_a(col_a,tb_b_id)
SELECT 2000 , id 
FROM table_b
```